# MySQL/PHP will not insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to add an email confirmation system to my website when people sign up and create an account but it will not add the key and the user id in the database.  The other problem I'm running across is I'm trying to send a confirmation email but the email does not send.  It echo's "message sent successfully" but when I check the email I put in, it is not received.  Thanks in advance for your help!  And yes, I am aware that mysql is prone to sql injection, but I would like to figure this out with mysql.

Here is my code:

**EDIT:** I replaced $insert_confirm with $hin and I renamed the table confirm to email_confirmation to maybe get rid of reserved words but I'm still getting an error

```
<?php

require_once '../scripts2/app_config.php';
require_once '../scripts2/database_connection.php';


$upload_dir = HOST_WWW_ROOT . "/uploads/profile_pics/";
$image_fieldname = "user_pic";


$first_name = trim($_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = trim($_REQUEST['last_name']);
$name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
$username = trim($_REQUEST['username']);
$password = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
$email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
$bio = trim($_REQUEST['bio']);

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {

   if($_POST['picture'] == 'picture1') {
      $radio_value = "/home/users/web/b2620/ipg.knecktcom/testphp/uploads/profile_pics/1387503042-autopicture2.png";
    } else if($_POST['picture'] == 'picture2') {
      $radio_value = "/home/users/web/b2620/ipg.knecktcom/testphp/uploads/profile_pics/1387547040-auto_pic_grey2.png";
    } else if($_POST['picture'] == 'picture3') {
      $radio_value = "/home/users/web/b2620/ipg.knecktcom/testphp/uploads/profile_pics/1387503042-autopicture2.png";
    } else {
      $radio_value = "/home/users/web/b2620/ipg.knecktcom/testphp/uploads/profile_pics/1387503042-autopicture2.png";
   }
}

$bgcolor = "#FF0000";


$check_email = "SELECT `email`" .
                          " FROM users" .
                          " WHERE `email` = '$email'";

$query_email = mysql_query($check_email);

$check_username = "SELECT `username`" .
                                 " FROM users" .
                                 " WHERE `username` = '$username'";
$query_username = mysql_query($check_username);

if(mysql_num_rows($query_email)>0 || mysql_num_rows($query_username)>0 ) {
     if(mysql_num_rows($query_email)>0) {
     $email_msg = "This email is already taken:  {$email}";
     header("Location:signup2.php?error_message={$email_msg}");
     } else if(mysql_num_rows($query_username)>0) {
     $username_msg = "This username is already taken:  {$username}";
     header("Location:signup2.php?error_message={$username_msg}");
     } else {
     $msg = "This email and username is already taken:  {$email} ,  {$username}";
     header("Location:signup2.php?error_message={$msg}");
     }
} else {

$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users " .
                              "(first_name, last_name, name, username, " .
                              "password, email, " . 
                              "bio, " .
                              "user_pic_path, bgcolor) " .
    "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s',
                         '%s', '%s', '%s');",
         mysql_real_escape_string($first_name),
         mysql_real_escape_string($last_name),
         mysql_real_escape_string($name),
         mysql_real_escape_string($username),
         mysql_real_escape_string(crypt($password, $username)),
         mysql_real_escape_string($email),
         mysql_real_escape_string($bio),
         mysql_real_escape_string($radio_value),
         mysql_real_escape_string($bgcolor));

//insert the user into the database
$insert_user = mysql_query($insert_sql);
$private_user_id = mysql_insert_id();

function generateRandomString($length = 20) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$private_user_key = generateRandomString();

$hin = sprintf("INSERT INTO email_confirmation " .
                              "(user_id, key) " .
    "VALUES (%d, '%s');",
         mysql_real_escape_string($private_user_id),
         mysql_real_escape_string($private_user_key));

//insert the user into the database
mysql_query($hin);
echo mysql_error();

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$create_user_table = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$email."` ( friend_id INT, friend_status INT)");

if($insert_user && $create_user_table) {

// Email the new user the confirmation key
$to      = $email;
$subject = 'Welcome!';
$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Please click the following link to confirm your email:</p>
  <p><a href=\"confirmation_email.php?user_id=$private_user_id&key=$private_user_key\">Confirm Email</a></p>
</body>
</html>
";
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Admin <email@email.com>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
$retval = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if( $retval == true )
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
      echo "\n" . $to . "\n" . $message . "\n" . "\n" . $subject;
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
}



//Redirect this user to the page that displays user information
// $msg = "Please check your email to confirm your email address";
// header("Location: newuser_signinA.php?error_message={$msg}");
// exit();


}

?>
```

Comment: Your script is [prone to SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com) and also [the mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: Diagnosing issues with why mail won't send from your script could be the subject of a book. Do yu have a mail engine set up on the server? Is it configured correctly? Also take note from the [PHP mail docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php): `Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.

It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.`

Comment: I have a few different email addresses that I created with my server.  I couldn't tell you if it was configured correctly, I would hope it is...I received one of my emails that got sent from it but not any of the other 10 times i tried.

Comment: And could you tell me what is wrong with the `confirm` table?  About why it's not going in

Comment: Use `echo mysql_error();` directly after `mysql_query($insert_sql);` to figure out what the problem is -- but take note of TimWolla's suggestion.

Comment: With `mysql_error();` I get `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES (118, 'fUJxvNct2ghsFPPL7GT2')' at line 1`

Comment: That is strange, can you echo the query to see what it looks like? Echo $insert_confirm

Comment: This is what I get from `echo $insert_confirm` - `INSERT INTO confirm (user_id, key) VALUES (119, 'kcThbEvQNoQxmYiVEF8k');`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: I'm at a loss, I renamed the `confirm` table to `email_confirmation` and am still getting an error

Comment: @CBroe Could you tell me what reserved words I am using that I am not seeing?

Comment: Maybe the one that exactly the part of SQL statement that the error message is quoting starts with …?

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Thank you so much, I really did not notice that that was a reserved word! I'll be sure to keep that in mind from now on!